# Sign In with LinkedIn is not present in Products list on Dev App

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to enable the permission scope: "r_liteprofile" and I've read that this can be enabled if "Sign In with LinkedIn" is turned on in the Products list, however I don't seem to have this option. I have only "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect", which doesn't give me the right permissions to ultimately retrieve the Person URN.

Do I need to get approval from LinkedIn Developer Support to be able to use the "r_liteprofile" permission?